# preloading only selected images

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for help in resolving following problem:
I have website with 2 sliders and resizable content,
I need to make that photos on site load when:
- when its visible in slider or on site it should onload with site
- when its not visible it should be preloaded

Important notes:

- I cannot change page html(all images have src attribute) - no possibility to set to css.
- I cannot use jQuery because i cannot wait for document.ready
- All have be done in way that user with very slow internet connection wouldn't notice.

Any clue how this can be done?

Comment: A rough overview: Using an assortment of javascript events(maybe some jQuery will make life easier) trigger ajax calls.

Comment: well site is generated from php not from me, but i'm kinda curious about chunk sending html to browser, any helpful links?

Answer (score 0):

Set the body tag to visibility:hidden in the html and do the loading in background... once you load everything on the page (with the slides and photos) then set that to visibility:visible.
This may help you in designing.

Comment: I would at least have a loading gif or something to let the user know the page is alive

Comment: I can't go that way, because i can't make changes to the way that visible content loads, i have to change only content that is invisible at first when someone get on the page.

Comment: From your questions i assumes, you dont want to touch your existing Visibility logic of the code....  This way you will not touch your existing visible content loads etc... you only hide the superset ... so that you wont touch the existing logic of visibility's... once you think your js code is completely loaded then set the parent element visible.

Comment: as i stated i cant make it with doing any change of html, or even css, i need to make changes for only for <img/> tags, eventually I think i could add some invisible elements to <footer>